# Can I run a program over ssh interactively?

Tags: ssh, interactive

When I ssh to a box without a command it gives me an interactive shell. If I were to explicitly say to run bash, it doesn't work interactively. I have to send an interrupt to stop. If I wanted to run an interactive program like mysql, can I do it without first starting the interactive shell?

Comment: SSH itself supports running processes and shell commands with or without an interactive shell. However your questions are vague and offtopic for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you may want to use Plink along side PuTTY.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to provide the `-t` option to `ssh`, which allocates a terminal through which you can interact with the remote command.

```
ssh -t host mysql
```

Comment: Ahhh - so THATS how to run MySQL over SSH and get a prompt!